# FTP Error - Permission issue?

Tags: ftp

I was doing a complete redesign of a website for a client and everything was going fine until I went to ftp it. The login and password that he gave me works fine, but when I try to upload the files an error message pops up saying:

An FTP error occurred - cannot create new folder. Access denied. The file may not exist or there could be a permission problem. Make sure you have proper authorization on the server and the server is properly configured.

I can see the files that are already on the server, so I know I'm connected fine, but how do I get this website online? Do I contact the previous coder of the website to make the files writable? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hosting service may require you to place all files to /www for example and deny access to anything else. You may try to reset user rights via that webhost's web interface. If the service allows for some ssh access, you can try using that to see where your problem is. If SFTP works, even better, you can use just that instead.